# Remove text from a returned string through applescript

Tags: applescript

I am using the following to find the home folder on a Mac

> get path to home folder

and it returns the following string...

> alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Office2-Spare:"

All I need is the information between the quotes. Is there way of pulling that out or deleting the word alias, the space and the quotes?

I have trawled the net but only found ways of trimming text from the end. Can anyone help?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alias is not really part of the response, it's telling you the data type.  You just need to tell it what data type you want.

```
Set thePath to (get path to home folder) as string
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `as text` parameter to get the HFS path representation:

```
get path to home folder as text
```